# How to preserve Cycles material colours when exporting to .obj format?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, file-format

When I export `.obj` files from scenes that use Cycles (and thus, materials with nodes etc), the material colours are not preserved in the `.mtl` file.

So, what can I do to avoid this?

Comment: Have you tried setting the veiwport color?

Comment: I can confirm that the viewport color in *Materials > Settings > Viewport color* does get exported as obj colors. (to make setting viewport colors easier, you can cut and paste colors by pressing `Ctrl+C` and `Ctrl+V` while hovering over color selectors.)

Comment: I never noticed that option! Weird...

Answer (score 2):

As [mentioned by Jebediah Kerman](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3494/how-to-preserve-cycles-material-colours-when-exporting-to-obj-format#comment5987_3494), the *viewport color* in *Material > Settings* is exported to the `.mtl` file:

[image]

If you only have a few simple materials, it can be quite trivial to copy the colors by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> while hovering over the color selection boxes.

If you have many materials, you could write a python script to take colors from the node tree and set the viewport color accordingly.

For example, here is a simple script that looks for diffuse shaders and sets the viewport color to the color of any diffuse shaders found:

```
import bpy

for mat in bpy.data.materials:
    if mat.use_nodes == True:
        tree = mat.node_tree
        for node in tree.nodes:
            if node.type == "BSDF_DIFFUSE":
                col = node.inputs["Color"].default_value
                mat.diffuse_color = (col[0],col[1],col[2])
```

Note that the *Viewport color* is actually [`diffuse_color`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_release/bpy.types.Material.html?highlight=diffuse%20color#bpy.types.Material.diffuse_color).